# Maven Tycho: Cannot add artifact descriptor which has not been created by this repository

Tags: maven, tycho, p2

I'm trying to build an RCP application via Tycho and I receive this error when exporting the product.

I don't really understand the issue, but could it be that the reason why it fails it's because I'm using multiple P2 repositories to retrieve my plugins dependencies?

This is the snipped of the repositories I've defined in my parent POM. The rest is pretty standard Tycho.

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>eclipse-luna</id>
    <url>${eclipseLuna}</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>systems-rc-p2</id>
    <url>${systemsRcP2}</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>systems-snapshots-p2</id>
    <url>${systemsSnapshotsP2}</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried to use a P2 group containing the all three repos in the example using a local nexus, in order to refer to only one repository, but I got the same error. My suspicion about the multiple p2 repositories, was wrong. I really have no idea. I will try to dig into the source code

Comment: It looks like I'm running into this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389698 because I have a patch and I'm trying to build a product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

Basically for some reason (project needs) I had to change the "sourceDirectory" and the "outputDirectory" of the project, pointing them to the classic "src" and "bin" instead of the Maven default "src/main" and "target".

In particular, what was causing the issue was the redefinition of the `<outputDirectory>` property and the `<directory>` one. It looks like Tycho does not like it at all.